# How do I make the landing page of website appear on Google and not "Index of /"?

Tags: wordpress, apache, indexing, google-search

I have recently made my WordPress website live and want it to be visible on Google Search. However, when specifically searching for the website, Google does not show the site title or description entered in WordPress, but rather "Index of /" and a bit of server info as the page summary. Does anyone recognize this, and have some ideas on how to fix this?

Apache2 is running on an Ubuntu 18.04 server and everything is updated. I have both an index.html file and obviously an index.php file in the DocumentRoot directory specified in the Virtual Host file for apache. And have specified to use index.php first in the .htaccess file. I've also tried to add the URL of the page to Google Search Console and added a sitemap, but with no effect.

Comment: Does site itself sereve a wordpress when you requesting your domain.com/ (not domain.com/index.html or domian.com/index.php) ?

Comment: @Butuzov The first time I access the site from a new device (phone, pc, tablet), typing in domain.com/ brings me to the index page I believe, but when I access it a second time it goes to the WordPress page.

Comment: I think I might have found something that can be causing the issue. The page that is shown on Google as "Index of /" is actually the http version which was there before I was able to add SSL. Is there a way to remove the http version from Google, but keeping the https one?

Answer (score 0):

You can add these lines to .htaccess files (its located in root of the website). What it does its redirects any trafic you got on http://example.com to https://example.com Please check both locations in separate browsers (and again with removed cache) on how it works. SOmetimes apache can be configured so it wouldn't work out of the box (like it can require additional fixes to redirection code or to the additional blocks etc...)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When adding these lines to the .htaccess file, the page turned into an all-text website. However, I realized that I didn't have an active virtualhost for port 80 or http. So added the line "Redirect / https://mywebpage.com/" to a virtual host file and used a2ensite to activate. This seemed to at least redirect from the http to the https site. I guess now I'll just have to wait for Google to index the site again and see if it shows a summary of the page and not just "Index of /".